# Rails problem assigning a method to an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I realize this is a bit of a novice question. I am trying to define a method `unread_notices`  and then call it for the `current_user`. Here's what I have:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def unread_notices
    Notice.where("read" => false)
  end

  def current_user
    User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
```

application.html.erb:

```
<li><%= link_to "Notices (#{current_user.unread_notices.count})", notices_path %></li>
```

`unread_notices` works, until I filter it with `current_user`, then it says `undefined method 'unread_notices' for #<User:0x110dd0f48>`. Any thoughts? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notices, :dependent => :destroy

class Notice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: How are the User and Notice models linked up? Does User has_many :notices ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a scope on your Notice model:

```
class Notice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :unread, where("read" => false)
end
```

and use it like this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Notices (#{current_user.notices.unread.count})", notices_path %></li>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Never would have thought of doing it this way, but I'm learning...

Comment: @Tony the documentation is pretty useful, read it and you will be an expert on scopes in no time: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

The name of the relationship is 'notices' not 'unread_notices'. For you to filter unread_notices by User, you can define a scope in the User model something like this:

```
Class Notice < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :unread_notices, lambda {
    where(:read => false)
  }
end
```

Read more here: http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html

Comment: This won't work, it will look for a `read` attribute on the users table. Besides, I don't think you can return notices with a scope on the User class

Comment: Updated. Typed in a hurry. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I'd have called the scope `unread`, calling it with `notices.unread_notices` looks a bit redundant. But I guess this is a matter of taste :-)